# How to put ads on every web page?

Tags: http, proxy, ads

I am wondering how to put ads like the software Hotspot Shield does.  It puts ads on the top of every web page.  I don't want in a specific language like vb or c++ i just want how in any language.

Examples:

- http://ishtechnology.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/Blog-Ad-added-by-Hotspot-Shield-e1288306756847.png
- http://www.raymond.cc/images/hotspot-shield-advertisements.png

Answer (score 2):

Beside from the obvious evilness of this, the solution is quite simple : install a transparent http proxy on the machine and decorate each and every page with the html code required to display add.

Did I say that kind of behaviour was simply bad ? It indeed [defaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Website_defacement) web pages, for the sole purpose of displaying adds that will rarely be clicked.

Comment: Can you explain please because i didn't understand you very well (an exemple will be very helpful ) thenx